# TypeError: Cannot read property "9" from undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, typeerror, undefined

I'm looking to delete rows of a given spreadsheet using the code below, but am receiving the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "9" from undefined." When testing the `For loop` and setting it as `i = 20`, the code works, but as `i = data.length`, it results in an error. Any ideas what the problem is? Thanks

```
function cleanUp() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for ( var i = data.length ; i > 0; i-- ) {
    if (data[i][9] === 'ERROR' || data[i][9] === 'BOUNCED' || data[i][9] === 'NO_RECIPIENT') {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Arrays in javascript (and most other languages, an exception would be lua) start at zero. Now do the math of "number of elements" vs "highest available element".

Comment: Hey, I appreciate you helping me think this through. If what you're asking is: "number of elements" - (minus) "highest avaiable element", then the answer is of course 0 (zero). Sorry I'm new at this, but I don't understand where in the code this knowledge applies.

Comment: Imagine an array with one element, `["element"]`. What's the `length` and what's the highest index `n` you can access (`["element"][n]`)?

Comment: length is 1, highest index is 0.

Comment: Now maybe you see the issue with `data[data.length]`?

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. It has been changed to `data.length - 1`

Comment: For your code, some languages (older c/c++ versions) would read in memory whatever is behind your array there and give you that (with possible though unlikely access violations for off-by-one, related topic: [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)), others (Java, C#, F#, ...) would throw an OutOfBoundsException, javascript gives you `undefined`, cause well, it's javascript and that's not the most questionable thing it does.

Comment: One last note, your `for` loop in turn has the condition `i > 0`, essentially skipping `data[0]` at the end. Unsure if intended, i don't really know google-apps-script and only addressed the immediate exception and issue from the title. You also call `deleteRow` with `i + 1`, but i again do not know the related API so cannot comment on it.

Comment: Really appreciate all your help. The `For` loop's `i > 0` is intentional, given that the first row is a header row. `deleteRow` is `i+1` because the syntax in `deleteRow` for Google-Apps-Script starts rows at 1, not 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ASDFGerte in the above comments, I found the issue was `data[i]` in the `if` statement nested inside the `for` loop. This essentially returned `data[data.length]` which was undefined. Instead, this works perfectly:

```
for ( var i = data.length-1 ; i > 0; i-- ) {
 if (data[i][9] === 'ERROR' || data[i][9] === 'BOUNCED' || data[i][9] === 'NO_RECIPIENT' || data[i][9] === 'UNSUBSCRIBED') {
  sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
 }
}
```